# How to use mapWithIndex in Purescript?

Tags: purescript

I'm a naive at Purescript, so I have a very basic issue while working with one of Purescript based frameworks.

I'm using `PrestoDOM` and I wonder how to use `mapWithIndex` function from `Data.Array` package.
I tried like the following,

```
import Data.Array (mapWithIndex)
...
  (mapWithIndex
    (\(item index) ->  // want to use both item and its index through loop
      textView [
        width MATCH_PARENT
        , height WRAP_CONTENT
        , text item
        , visibility index > 0 ? VISIBLE : GONE
      ]
    )
    data
  )
...
```

but I got this error:

```
Unable to parse module:
  unexpected [
  expecting indentation at column 1 or end of input
```

I know this error directly comes from my wrong use of `mapWithIndex`.

Comment: It's not your wrong use of `mapWithIndex`, it's how you define the lambda expression: parameters cannot be in parentheses. Should be `\item index -> ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve out the problem.
Wrong use of mapWithIndex - parameter order.

```
(mapWithIndex
    (\index item ->
      textView [
        width MATCH_PARENT
        , height WRAP_CONTENT
        , text item
        , visibility index > 0 ? VISIBLE : GONE
      ]
    )
    data
  )
```